# Grails order by for 1 to Many related objects

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp, one-to-one

In grails GSP I am doing something like

```
 <g:each in="${testInstance?.testConfigs?}" var="t">
```

Two classes are

```
class Test{
    static hasMany = [testConfigs:TestConfig]
}

class TestConfig {
    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated
    Test test
    static constraints = {
        dateCreated display:false
        lastUpdated display:false
        questionType inList:["Fill in the blanks","Multipl choice","True False"]
    }
}
```

How can I change the for each loop so that testConfigs objects are retrieved ordered descending by dateCreated field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does defining a sort order [like it says in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder) not work?

```
class Test{
    static hasMany = [testConfigs:TestConfig]

    static mapping = {
        testConfigs sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc'
    }
}
```

Comment: I was sure it must be there somewhere in the Docs, just didn't know where... Thanks a lot for not saying RTFM

Comment: @Grrrrr No worries!  There's so much documentation, esoteric things like this tend to get buried :-)  Good luck!